# How come my cursor is throwing a null pointer in my Android Contact Picker?

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-cursor

My source repository is available here
https://github.com/jackygrahamez/MayDay/tree/gradle2

I'm having trouble with the Android Contact picker. I have tried a few approaches to getting contact phone number. I seem to get a null when I try to return a string. I put my code in an activity otherwise I was getting errors in the fragment. I can get a cursor count of 1

**In the Fragment I create the activity**

```
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        contactPickerButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 int wizardState = ApplicationSettings.getWizardState(getActivity());
//               if(wizardState != AppConstants.WIZARD_FLAG_HOME_READY){
                     AppConstants.IS_BACK_BUTTON_PRESSED = true;
                     AppConstants.IS_BACK_BUTTON_PRESSED = true;
//               }
                launchContactPicker(v);
            }
        });
    }

    public void launchContactPicker(View view) {
        Intent contactPickerIntent = new Intent(ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        contactPickerIntent.setType(CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
        startActivityForResult(contactPickerIntent, PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST_ID);
    }
```

**The Wizard Activity I cat the result from the contact picker**

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.e("WizardActivity", "onActivityResult requestCode "+requestCode);
    Log.e("WizardActivity", "onActivityResult resultCode "+resultCode);
    Log.e("WizardActivity", "onActivityResult data "+data.getData().toString());
    if ((requestCode == PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST_ID) && (resultCode == RESULT_OK)) {
        contactPickerFragment.phoneNumberEditText.setText(getPhoneNumber(data.getData()));
    }
}

public String getPhoneNumber(Uri contactData) {
    String[] projection = {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER};
    Cursor cursor = getCursor(contactData, projection);
    /*
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
            new String[] {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER},
            ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "=?" + " AND "
                    + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "='" + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'",
            new String[] {String.valueOf(ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID)}, null);
    */
    Log.e("WizardActivity", "onActivityResult cursor "+cursor);
    //cursor.moveToNext();
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(0);
}

Cursor getCursor(Uri contactData, String[] projection) {
    //return getActivity().managedQuery(contactData, projection, null, null, null);
    Log.e("WizardActivity", "getCursor "+getContentResolver().query(contactData, projection, null, null, null).getCount());
    return getContentResolver().query(contactData, projection, null, null, null);
}
```

Here is the log output

```
02-22 12:27:17.488    3535-3535/com.mayday.md E/WizardActivity﹕ onActivityResult requestCode 65636
02-22 12:27:17.488    3535-3535/com.mayday.md E/WizardActivity﹕ onActivityResult resultCode -1
02-22 12:27:17.488    3535-3535/com.mayday.md E/WizardActivity﹕ onActivityResult data content://com.android.contacts/data/10569
02-22 12:27:17.508    3535-3535/com.mayday.md E/WizardActivity﹕ getCursor 1
02-22 12:27:17.508    3535-3535/com.mayday.md E/WizardActivity﹕ onActivityResult cursor android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner@42c6a018
02-22 12:27:17.508    3535-3535/com.mayday.md D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
02-22 12:27:17.508    3535-3535/com.mayday.md W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4172fda0)
02-22 12:27:17.518    3535-3535/com.mayday.md E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.mayday.md, PID: 3535
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=65636, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.contacts/data/10569 flg=0x1 }} to activity {com.mayday.md/com.mayday.md.WizardActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3663)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3706)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:173)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1351)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5579)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.mayday.md.WizardActivity.onActivityResult(WizardActivity.java:327)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5643)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3659)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3706)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:173)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1351)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5579)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: It should be `cursor.moveToFirst();` instead of `cursor.movetoNext()`. Can you also post your code of `startActivityforResult` code.

Comment: @Ranjith I tried your suggestion and provided updated log errors above

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error its due to startActivityForResult:
Try below code:

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI), PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST_ID);
```

Comment: i got a new error `Invalid column data1` do you want to take this to a chat?

Comment: I created a room https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71436/how-come-my-cursor-is-throwing-a-null-pointer-in-my-android-contact-picker

Comment: There is lot of code in the rep...which line are you getting this error now? Whats the code there or mention the filename and the line number, I can look in the repo

Answer (score 0):

I have taken another approach to creating the cursor and it seems to work well `getContextResolver()`.

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data, Context context) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.e("ContactPickerFragment", "onActivityResult requestCode "+requestCode);
    Log.e("ContactPickerFragment", "onActivityResult resultCode "+resultCode);
    Log.e("ContactPickerFragment", "onActivityResult data "+data);

    ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
    Cursor cur = cr.query(data.getData(), null, null, null, null);
    String phone = "";
    if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cur.moveToNext()) {
            String id = cur.getString(
                    cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            Log.e("ContactPickerFragment", "onActivityResult id "+id);
            String name = cur.getString(
                    cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
            Log.e("ContactPickerFragment", "onActivityResult name "+name);
            if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                //Query phone here.  Covered next
                Cursor pCur = cr.query(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                        null,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?",
                        new String[]{id}, null);
                Log.e("WizardActivity", "onActivityResult pCur "+pCur);
                while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                    // Do something with phones
                            phone = pCur.getString(
                            pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                    Log.e("ContactPickerFragment", "onActivityResult phone "+phone);
                    }
                pCur.close();
            }
        }
    }
    Log.e("ContactPickerFragment", "onActivityResult phone "+phone);
    phone = phone==null?"":phone.trim();
    Log.e("ContactPickerFragment", "onActivityResult phoneNumberEditText "+phoneNumberEditText);
    phoneNumberEditText.setText(phone);
    //phoneNumberEditText.setText(phone);
    //phoneNumberEditText.setText((CharSequence)phone);
}
```